# Como poner imagen de fondo en un contenedor

Tags: css

tengo un div que le coloco una imagen de fondo el problema es que no queda centrada como la quiero , como podria centrarla? aqui esta mi codigo

```
 <div id="main"></div>



#main{ 

    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-image: url("img/wall_color.png");

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan sencillo como ponerle una posición centrada ejemplo:

```
.main{ 
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color:grey;
        background-image: url("img/wall_color.png");
        background-position: 50% 50%;//aqui ocupara el 50 por ciento a ambos lados 
     }
```

Comment: ey gracias andy me funciono bien!

Answer (score 0):

Agrega lo siguiente a tu `id` `main`

```
#main{
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Si la altura no es la adecuada, prueba colocando una a tu gusto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregarle un id para reconocer tu contenedor en css, y luego

```
#main
{
   background-size: 100% 100%; /*Con esto ocupas el 100% del contenedor*/
   background-repeat: no-repeat;  /*Evitas que la imagen se repita si el contenedor es mas grande*/
   background-image:url("img/wall_color.png"); /*Ten en cuenta que la ruta es relativa y empezara desde el lugar donde tengas el css*/
}
```

Con esto ya podrás agregar el fondo a cualquier contenedor.